# Split dataframe to several dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have following code:

```
Date                   X          
...
2014-12-30 23:00:00    2
2014-12-30 23:15:00    0
2014-12-30 23:30:00    1
2014-12-30 23:45:00    1
2014-12-31 00:00:00    22
...
2015-01-01 00:00:00    0
2015-01-02 00:00:00    2
2015-01-03 00:00:00    2
2015-01-04 00:00:00    2
2015-01-04 00:00:00    2
2015-01-05 00:00:00    2
...
```

I want to split this time series (dataframe) into many time series (dataframe). I would like to have one time series for each Monday, one for all Tuesdays, Wednesdays ... etc.

How can I do that with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `dictionary of DataFrames` with `groupby` and [`weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html):

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.weekday_name)))

#select by days
print (dfs['Friday'])
        Date  X
6 2015-01-02  2

print (dfs['Thursday'])

        Date  X
5 2015-01-01  0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['Date'].dt.weekday_name)
0       Tuesday
1       Tuesday
2       Tuesday
3       Tuesday
4     Wednesday
5      Thursday
6        Friday
7      Saturday
8        Sunday
9        Sunday
10       Monday
Name: Date, dtype: object
```